# Spring WebFlux: block() method return null in Spring Data Reactive MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, project-reactor, reactive-streams

i'm trying to learn project Reactor and have the problem.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("check that standaloneUser fields are correct")
void validateUserFields() {
    userService.save(standaloneUser).subscribe();
    assertEquals(userService.count().block(), Long.valueOf(1));
    User user = userService.findByEmail("test@gmail.com").block();
    assertNotNull(user);
    assertNotNull(user.getId());
    assertEquals(user.getFirstName(), "test");
    assertEquals(user.getLastName(), "test");
    assertNotEquals(user.getPassword(), "test");
    assertEquals(user.getRole(), Role.CANDIDATE);
    assertNotNull(user.getCreatedDate());
    assertNull(user.getStoppedDate());
    assertEquals(user.getEmail(), "test@gmail.com");
}
```

Sometimes block() method returns null.
Who can explain me this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`block()` *can* return null, it means the `Mono` completed empty, which in this case means the user wasn't found.

Could it be that it wasn't properly saved? (although you assert the user count)

Note that you do `userService.save(standaloneUser).subscribe()`. This form is often not ideal, as it is "async fire-and-forget":

- async -> it might complete **after** the subsequent asserts
- fire and forget -> no error handler means that it **could terminate with an error and hide it from you**.

Make an habit of at least setting onNext and onError handler lambdas when calling `subscribe`.